# Solving PDE with Neumann on a finite Interval

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

> $\partial_t u= k\partial^2_x u , 0<x<\pi, t>0 \\
> u(x,0)=cos^2 (x) + sin^2 (3x) \\
> \partial_xu(0,t)=\partial_x u(\pi,t)=0 $

This is a PDE I am given to solve.  My question is to just verify the follwing: Where is the initial condition stated used to solve this Neumann Heat Equation?

I know that:

> $u(x,t)= 1/2 A_0 + \sum A_n e^{-(n\pi/l)^2kt}cos(n\pi x/l)\\
>  \phi(x)= 1/2 A_0 + \sum A_n cos(n\pi x/l) $.

Edit: Looking at the question a bit closer, is the problem just asking to solve for the unknown constants given $\phi(x)$?

Comment: You get the unknown coefficients $A_i$ by plugging in $t=0$ and setting equal to the initial conditions.

Comment: @Neal I see that now, but am unsure how to proceed given that the general form of $\phi(x)$ is given in the form of a sum and the initial condidtion is the sum of two trigonometric functions.

Comment: Use the orthogonality of different-frequency trig functions.

Comment: @Neal Assuming I did everything correctly, my conclusion is that all $A_i$ are zero except for $A_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have
$$\phi(x) = \cos^2(x)+sin^2(2x) = u(x,0) = \frac{1}{2}A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos(n\pi x/l).$$
I'm assuming that the problem should be posed for $0<x<l$, otherwise I cannot see where the $l$ comes from.

Integrate this equation, and you obtain $A_0 = 2\int_0^l\phi(x)$. To obtain the rest of the $A_n's$ simply multiply the equation by $\cos(m\pi x/l)$ and integrate from $0$ to $l$, utilising the orthogonality of the set of functions $\{\cos(m\pi x/l)\}_{m=0}^\infty$.